# How can I place 3 diagrams next to each other?

Tags: subfloats, minipage

I am trying to put three diagrams next to each other, but it does not work. If I use subfigure the third figure is below the others, even if there is enough space for all three in a row. Now I tried to include minipages, but I am not sure how to position the diagrams next to each other now:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.9}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

%Start figure 1
     \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Capacity},
    ylabel={Service Level in \%},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,90.92)(4,97.65)(6,99.94 )(8,100 )(10,100)
    };
\end{axis};
                \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    


%Start figure 2
     \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
     {\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Capacity},
    ylabel={Costs in €},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=1000,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,909.83)(4,740.87)(6,740.87)(8,740.87)(10,740.87)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}\hfill


    
    
    
%Start figure 3
     \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Sensitivity Analysis Service Level vs Costs},
    xlabel={Service Level in \%},
    ylabel={Costs in €},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=1000,
    xtick={100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0},
    ytick={100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (90.92,909.82)(90,850.60)(80, 712.71)(70, 712.71)(60,666.11)(50,645.72)(40,645.72)(30,645.72)(20,645.72)(10,646.72)(0,645.72)
    };
  
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}\hfill

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should try the `floatrow` package.

Comment: 0.45 * 3 > 1 so this width should be something like 0.3. And there should not be empty lines between minipage. It then can be put on the same line but the tikz plot looks squeezed. Add a `scalebox` may help the three figures look better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! It works now with 0.3 width and without the empty lines. At what point to I include the scalebox? If I include it after {0.3\textwidth} the figures are overlapping.

Comment: Are you going to add a separate caption for each plot?

Comment: Yes, I will try to add captions as soon as the diagrams are positioned correctly. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Why you use so old version of  the `pgfplots` package? I suggest you to upgrade it to recent version (1.18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, empty lines are paragraph breaks, so you've essentially placed the diagrams in three separate paragraphs, and hence three separate lines. This is just the same as normal text, actually. In addition, the total width of the minipages should be less than `\textwidth`, so change `0.45` to e.g. `0.32`.

I disagree with the suggestion to use `scalebox`, I think it's better to adjust the settings of the diagram. `pgfplots` has a few predefined styles to make things smaller, they are `tiny`, `footnotesize` and `small`. If you apply the `footnotesize` style and modify the width you can get the following:

[image]

The other modifications are mainly to replace `minipage` by `subfigure` and add the optional `[t]` argument to fix an alignment problem. The misalignment was mostly from breaking the title of the third axis across two lines, because it was too wide. Captions are added in the normal way.  (Note that a `subfigure` environment as defined by the `subcaption` package is more or less just a `minipage`, but a `\caption` added inside it is seen as a caption for a subfigure.)

If you want Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 3 instead of Figure 1a, 1b, 1c, simply replace `subfigure` by `minipage` again.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\pgfplotsset{
    footnotesize, % reduces font size and size of diagram
    width=\linewidth, % modify size of axis
}
%Start figure 1
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
      \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Capacity},
    ylabel={Service Level in \%},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,90.92)(4,97.65)(6,99.94 )(8,100 )(10,100)
    };
\end{axis};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{foo}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Capacity},
    ylabel={Costs in €},
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=1000,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    ytick={0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,909.83)(4,740.87)(6,740.87)(8,740.87)(10,740.87)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{bar}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Sensitivity Analysis\\Service Level vs Costs}, % <-- added \\
    title style={align=center}, % <-- added
    xlabel={Service Level in \%},
    ylabel={Costs in €},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=1000,
    xtick={100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0},
    ytick={100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,line width=0.5mm,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (90.92,909.82)(90,850.60)(80, 712.71)(70, 712.71)(60,666.11)(50,645.72)(40,645.72)(30,645.72)(20,645.72)(10,646.72)(0,645.72)
    };
  
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{baz}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{foobarbaz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much for your explanations!